# JavaFX full screen application always on top

Tags: java, javafx, always-on-top

I have application written in JavaFX and I set primary stage as full screen and always on top:

```
primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

In background thread I start another application and window from this application appears over my window (this window have also probably property "always on top").

How can I configure my window to be always on top?

Comment: So you have a full screen window. You open another window, but you never want to actually display it on the screen? I don't really understand this. Btw, you should call `setFullScreenExitKeyCombination` before you call `setFullScreen`, as on `setFullScreen` an internal copy is made from the combination, therefore setting the key combination after actually does nothing.

Comment: My application have to run another application and I never want to display window from this another application. I can control this second application by TCP messages, so I don't need display windows from this application...

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
primaryStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

Comment: I can't init modality because this is primary stage. When I try to set this I get exception: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set modality for the primary stage`